# Переход начальная форма

Tags: ms-access

Можете помочь и подсказать, с помощью чего сделан переход между запросами формами и т.д в главной форме?
[Сам файл microsoft access](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1V7cq5BkpqJn3b5ImhCAMIRZsWfXPKXOw/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0):

При помощи [Embedded Macro] в 2 команды.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Да - конечно! (мой ответ краткий)

Итак:
Динозавры не пили кофе по утрам, и вымерли.
Логический вывод: Для выживания исчезающих видов - их нужно научить пить кофе.

Макросы = тупиковая ветвь развития в среде MS Access.
Это как ... = делать операцию на сердце при помощи топора и кувалды.

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Да конечно! Динозавры не пили кофе и вымерли.